# Story involving man who enters a web of wormholes with only a spacesuit

Tags: story-identification, wormhole

I read this in the mid-to-late 1970s, I think, and it was from the 1960s or possibly earlier.  I bought a lot of cheap SF paperbacks from my local second-hand book-exchange shop around that time.

It was some kind of SF action adventure.  The only thing I can remember about it is that at some point in the story, the hero (who may have been a spy or detective or something like that) travels through an interstellar wormhole in only a spacesuit (or perhaps normal clothing).  This turned out to be an advantage for him because his enemies did not expect him to be able to travel like this.

I'm not sure if he did this normally, or if it was a risk he took due to circumstances. I think the latter.  I'm pretty sure it was a dangerous, non-standard way of using wormholes.  The wormholes were an interstellar transport network (human-made, I think). I think the wormholes linked planets directly to each other, not star systems.

The wormholes may have been described as being golden in colour.

The title may have had the word "Web" in it.

Sorry for the vagueness, but I really don't remember much more than "man goes in wormhole without a ship but survives".

---

NOTE: this is not John Brunner's Web of Everywhere, that's a completely different story.